# How can I hide Spinner Loader after all data is fetched - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How can I hide the loading spinner after all the data has been fetched from the API? I have a laravel api that outputs paginated data. I am using reactjs to display the data with scroll event.
Now I want to hide the spinner when all the data has been fetched. Or add something like `No more data`

Here is my code

```
function Training() {
let navigate = useNavigate();
const [fruits, setFruits] = useState([]);
const [limit, setLimit] = useState(6);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {

    let isMounted = true;

    axios.get(`/api/fruits?page=1&limit=` + limit).then(res => {
        if (isMounted) {
            if (res.data.status === 200) {
                setFruits(res.data.fruit);
                setIsLoading(false);
                setLoading(false);
                console.warn(res.data.fruit.length)
            }
        }
    });
    return () => {
        isMounted = false
    };
}, [limit]);

useEffect(() => {

    const handleScroll = (e) => {
        const scrollHeight = e.target.documentElement.scrollHeight
        const currentHeight = e.target.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight
        if (currentHeight + 1 >= scrollHeight) {
            setLoading(true);
            setLimit(limit + 4)
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
}, [limit])
```

To show the data and the loading spinner

```
<div className="section">

                <div className="row">
                    {isLoading && <WidgetSkeleton cards={6} />}

                    {fruits.map((fruit) => (
                        <FruitWidget fruit={fruit} key={fruit.id} />
                    ))}

                </div>
                {loading ? <><span className="spinner-border spinner-center text-primary mb-5" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span></> : ''}

            </div>
```

Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

here in you code
You are turning on the `setLoading` to `true` and and to hide spin loader you need to `setLoading(false)` which you are doing,

The problem is you are only setting `setloading` to false only if you receive data, you should instead.

```js
axios
  .get(`/api/fruits?page=1&limit=` + limit)
  .then((res) => {
    if (isMounted) {
      if (res.data.status === 200) {
        setFruits(res.data.fruit);
        console.warn(res.data.fruit.length);
      }
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  .finally(() => {
    setIsLoading(false);
    setLoading(false);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if res.data.fruit.length is less than your limit. Then we know that there are no more items to fetch.